# How do I overwrite property if exists?

Tags: javascript

Say I have object as follows:

```
let newObject = {
 foo: 'foo-value',
 bar: 'bar-value', 
 baz: 'baz-value'
};
```

I have also a list:

```
let list = ['foo', 'baz']
```

I want to overwrite 'foo-value' and 'baz-value' (value of keys that appear in the list) with some 'default-value'. So I have:

```
{
 foo: 'default-value',
 bar: 'bar-value', 
 baz: 'default-value'
};
```

If I have a different object, let's say

```
let differentObject = {
 x: 'x-value',
 y: 'y-value'
}
```

I don't want to add any default value so spread operator didn't work for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Where do you get the "default-value"?

Comment: `list.forEach(k => obj[k] = 'default-value');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that like this

```js
let newObject = {
 foo: 'foo-value',
 bar: 'bar-value', 
 baz: 'baz-value'
};

let list = ['foo', 'baz'];

list.forEach(item => {
  if(newObject[item])
   newObject[item] = 'Default value';
})

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Where is the check that the property exists? I only see a check that the resolved property value is truthy. This is also problematic because it creates new properties if they were only inherited before.

Comment: @SebastianSimon `if(newObject[item])` checks both of them

Comment: So it’s not what is being asked for, then. This simply _fails_ for ``let newObject = { foo: "", bar: 0, baz: false }; Object.prototype.inherited = "this property does not exist on `newObject`."; let list = [ "foo", "bar", "baz", "inherited" ];``.